# how to show a vertical video in a horizontal rectangle box in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-video-player

I have a video player that play videos in a rectangle box
my current video is a vertical video,
but I want to crop it in this rectangle with `fit:BoxFit.cover`

this is my code

```
Container(
  height: 194,

  width: Get.width,
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(width: 2,
          color: Colors.green),
    ),
    child:  FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
          child:SizedBox(
              width: 16/9,
              height: 1,
              child: VideoPlayer(oldController)
      ),
    ),
    width: 80,
    height: 20,
  ),

        //FURTHER IMPLEMENTATION

  )
```

by above code the result is like this
[image]

but the result should be like this
[image]

I changed the width of the [image]Sized box in my code and get this result

and it is the code that related to above picture

```
Container(
  height: 194,

  width: Get.width,
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(width: 2,
          color: Colors.green),
    ),
    child:  FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
          child:SizedBox(
              width: 6.2,
              height: 1,
              child: VideoPlayer(oldController)
      ),
    ),
    width: 80,
    height: 20,
  ),

        //FURTHER IMPLEMENTATION

  )
```

but it is not a good result ,
the best result is picture 2

I want to crop the video like this
[image]

I try boxfit.fitWidth but it didnot work

Comment: No friend,I don't want to scale it, I just want to crop the video.